# How to use rails or sql to query through has_many association?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

```
class Movie
  has_many :movie_genres
  has_many :genres, through: :movie_genres
end
```

I want find basically films that are not 'Short'.

I tried `joins(:genres).where('genres.name is not ?', 'Short')`, but seems to be returning movies whose first genre isn't 'Short' instead.

Comment: Is there any relation made between Movie and MovieGenre? 

once you set association between MovieGenres and Movie, then you can do `joins(:genres).where('genres.name is not ?', 'Short')`

Comment: @NarenSisodiya yes, edited. also that solution doesn't work in this game, for some reason, it only filters out movies where first genre is 'Short'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to find out all movies which are having genre as 'Short' and then exclude those movies from final list. Try out something like following:

```
Movie.where.not(id: Movie.joins(:genres).where('genres.name = ?', 'Short').pluck(:id))
```

Comment: nice, that does work but i was hoping to get it out of the way in a nicer format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use where with not like below

```
Movie.joins(:genres).where.not('genres.name = ?', 'Short')
```